# React-admin rendering runtime resources multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

I'm following [this](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#unplugging-the-admin-using-admincontext-and-adminui) design pattern from React-admin to define the parent `Team` resource,
but the useEffect hook is being called 4 times on every page refresh

The context provider is just to be able to pass the `Teams` list to a select in the layout, if I remove it, the same problem happens

Is this expected behaviour?

```
const AdminEnterprise = () => {
  return (
    <AdminContext
      disableTelemetry
      authProvider={authProvider}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <TeamResources />
    </AdminContext>
  );
};

const TeamResources = () => {
  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(teamReducer, {
    loading : true,
    teams : []
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    //This is called 4 times on page refresh
    console.log('querying user teams')
    dataProvider.getList('userTeams')
      .then(({data}) =>{
        dispatch({
          teams: data,
          selected: data[0].id,
          loading: false
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
          error: error,
          loading: false
        })
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <TeamContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {state.loading? <></> : (
        <AdminUI layout={MyLayout} loginPage={CustomLoginPage} theme={myTheme}>
          <Resource name={`teams/${state.selected}/projects`} list={ProjectList} options={{label: 'Projects' }}/>
          <Resource name={`teams/${state.selected}`} />
        </AdminUI>
      )}     
    </TeamContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: You are updating the state from inside the useEffect hook. Try wrapping the dispatch with an if statement. Like `if (state.teams.length === 0 || state.teams === null) dispatxh({...})`

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you have root re-rendering from the `AdminEnterprise` component, your `TeamResources` is correct, but you can optimize it from top-level or optimize it by using `React.memo` inside the `TeamResources` component (recommended). You can export it by `memo`:

```js
const TeamResources = () => {
  ~ ~ ~
};

export default React.memo(TeamResources);
```

For tuning the `React.memo` you can have more information [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/)

Comment: I'm afraid doing this wasn't enough, same issue

Comment: @Mojimi, definitely, anything cannot be enough, you know, in your case you need to fix it as soon as possible, then comeback and find the cause of root re-rendering. so my answer could be a valuable rapid solution, but for future yeah, you should come back and find the causes.

Answer (score 1):

The "expected" behaviour is for anything inside useEffect() with an empty dependency array ([] as the second argument) to only run once.

The AdminContext tree is likely re-rendering based on changes to dataProvider or some other side-effects of invoking dataProvider.getList(). We can't see that, so it's tough to help.

Here's at least a suggested method to verify that the problem isn't inside TeamResources:

```
# in Test.jsx
const Test = () => {
  console.log('Test is rendering.');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Test, inside useEffect');
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};

# in AdminContext.jsx

    <AdminContext
      disableTelemetry
      authProvider={authProvider}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <Test />
      <TeamResources />
    </AdminContext>
```

I'd suspect that 'Test, inside useEffect' is going to be logged more often than expected too.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `authProvider` or `dataProvider` change asynchronously. Therefore `AdminContext` component re-renders is again. So check it in the `AdminEnterprise` component.

```
const AdminEnterprise = () => {
  if (!authProvider || !dataProvider) return null;
  return (
    <AdminContext
      disableTelemetry
      authProvider={authProvider}
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
    >
      <TeamResources />
    </AdminContext>
  );
};
```